# vue-chartjs not working properly in flexbox and when resize chart goes blank

Tags: flexbox, chart.js, bulma, vue-chartjs

I'm using vue-chartjs but every time I resize it, it's not layout properly anymore. It goes beyond the screen. Also when I resize it, the chart went missing but it will appear after a while but sometimes it just went white. Btw, I'm using Bulma for my responsive framework.

[image]

It should look like on this photo.

[image]

Here's one of my code

```
<script>
import { HorizontalBar, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs';

const { reactiveProp } = mixins;

export default {
  extends: HorizontalBar,
  mixins: [reactiveProp],
  props: ['chartData', 'options'],
  mounted() {
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      responsiveAnimationDuration: 5,
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
          },
          barThickness: 10,
          maxBarThickness: 5,
          categoryPercentage: 0.2,
        }],
      },
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is related to this bug: https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs/issues/288

Which is fixed in the latest version. So you should just update your dependencies.